# Custom filter() in Processing

Tags: image-processing, processing

I am new to Processing Programming Language, I was wondering that if I can use different Structured Element in [Erosion and Dilation](http://processing.org/reference/filter_.html) Process as we can use in [`MATLAB`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Processing API offers erosion and dilation "as is", they don't take arguments and they do what they say they do on the docs page you reference. So if the question is "can I do something else?" then yes, if you write your own `PShader`, http://processing.org/reference/PShader.html, but not if you use the default presets.